# how to save data in table in angular ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know how to store data in HTML5 table .
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/
but I want to store data in table using angular.I make two field name and class.I want to make student table and insert name and class in that on button click. ? can we do that in angular ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/jopRDquecfuizJjiHe5U?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('appstart', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  //  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'tem.html',
      controller: 'ctrl'
    })


  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
});

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', "$location",
  function(s, $location) {

    s.add = function() {
      var email = $('#inputName').val();
      var password = $('#inputclass').val();


    }


  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found several mistakes in your approach..

Firstly, var password = $('#inputclass').val(); is not the way to retrieve data, you instead should use ng-model

Anyways, i have made changes to your plunker and added a fork.. check it out and revert back if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: can you please give fiddle of plunker ?

Comment: sir you are making list but.I want to save in data base..Mean as we do in HTML5 sqlite

Comment: Server side DB or client side DB ??

Comment: As we if I add name and class it added in table .and we can check using inspect and resouces

Comment: client side ..I know 3 way to store localstorage,session storage.I know how to implement in angular..But there is table way i don't know that

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/ ..in this example it create a table ..can we do the same thing in angular mean to create table of student and add column of name and class

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concerned, Angular is not meant to create tables or any such client side data store.. what you can do is, integrate Angular Js with a library that does so.. All you need to do is, put the table creation and data insertion in the controller methods and let that library handle the data insertions for ya..

Comment: thanks for update ..do you know any library ?if yes please integrate on my plunker ..

Comment: make a simple example on plunker.so that I understant the thinks properly